# How to explicitly exclude assemblies in test runner during TFS Build

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tfs

In my solution I have c++ and c# projects with corresponding Unit test projects mixed. During a TFS build I only want to execute the C# unit tests. Unfortunately I can't find a way to exclude these test assemblies to be being used in the unit test runner. I could identify all c++ unit tests projects based on a naming patter like Native.Tests.dll.

**I can't find a way to explicitly exclude certain test assemblies from being tested/executed from the test runner.**

Is there a way through either

- Test Case Filter
- Test assembly file specification?

Environment:

- TFS 2013
- Process template: ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml

**In case you are wondering: Why do I want to exclude certain assemblies?**

I want to use the Test Category feature to exclude certain unit tests from being executed on the build server, which you do through the TestCaseFilter feature in the TFS template. You specify that per "Test batch". When I run all my unit tests (c# + c++) in one test settings the native unit tests throw an error, because they don't understand/support the TestCategory-filter feature (remember: Test Case Filter). Therefore I want to split the it in 2 test runs/batches: c++ and c#.

Answer (score 0):

Test Category is only worked in C# test project. (Test in my environment: TFS2015 VS2015)

If you only want to execute the C# unit test. The simplest way you can specify the C# test assembly file in Test assembly file specification. 
You just need to identify all C# unit tests projects based on a naming patter totally different as C++ tests projects.

**Note:** You must make sure you are using totally different naming rules between C++ an C# test project.

For example:

```
C++test project name : including  ABC  like ABC1 ,ABC2, ABC3

C# test project name: including  XYZ  like XYZ1, XYZ2 ,XYZ3
```

Then using ***XYZ*.dll in Test assembly file specification to run the all C# test project.

Comment: That would mean I need to change the naming of all Unit test projects for c++ or c#. I was hoping to find a simpler way. I have a naming patern for native, because all of these projects include the word "Native.Tests.dll" in their name. Unfortunatly I can't exclude based on a pattern, but only include.

Comment: Did you must use Test category to split  the cases.Would you like try to use  priority attributes to organize and prioritize your tests?https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.priorityattribute.aspx